# Can someone hack a user account by setting cookies values in his computer?

Tags: php

I am testing a little chat WITH PHP  website and by the way I'm creating it, i fear someone can hack a user account by creating cookies in his computer.

the way i made my cookies is the following.

if the cookie is set, the cookie value is sent to the server that analyses it and determine the corresponding user then validates the user.
Thank you.

Comment: If the attacker controls the user's computer, you've already lost.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-10-13/web-authentication-arms-race-a-tale-of-two-security-experts/

Comment: It depends what you are storing in the cookie and how you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. If all I have to do is send a cookie you recognize to login, I'll just intercept a cookie from a legitimate user and send that.

You can avoid a lot of the issues with that by forcing that all connections are via SSL, but the "magic value in a cookie" setup is still vulnerable to other types of attack.

Comment: Thank you! it is really helping. i will have to learn further.